# Allow SPDesigner on some site collections but not allowed on others? [SP2013]

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, permissions, site-collection, web-application

I am wondering if, as the farm administrator, I can activate the SPDesigner features at the web application level, but ensure that site collection admins will not be able to activate SPDesigner on their site collections. I have a farm with a few thousand site collections with a few hundred unique site collection administrators. I do not trust giving all of them access to SPDesigner, but still want to use it for certain site collections.

Is there a way to prevent site collections admins from activating SPDesigner at the site collection level? Or prevent them from using Designer unless I specifically give them the correct permissions?